# How to eagerly load a complex graph in nhibernate that includes Any mappings

Tags: nhibernate, any

So, I have a large graph that is linked together using several different any relationships and I'm trying to figure out how to eagerly load the entire graph.

I have a Wizard which has a Step. The Step can either link directly to another Step or to some intermediate Action which will then link to another Step. Steps can link to other steps anywhere in the hierarchy; I do not want to load children of potentially recursive steps. I have them marked with a IsLink bool. There are several different kinds of steps, so anywhere something is linked to a Step, that is an Any mapping. Large graphs result in many database hits to load out the entire hierarchy.

Starting at the easiest thing I could think of:

```
        _session.QueryOver<Wizard>()
                .Where(w => w.Id == wizardId)
                .Fetch(w => w.Step).Eager
                .List().First();
```

results in the error: "any types do not have a unique referenced persister"

I'm not all that sure where to go from here to get this whole thing loading. I would prefer to get it done using NHibernate and not result to some massive stored procedure. The hierarchy works; I can recursively traverse and build out everything I want, but that's not very performant.

Where shall I start?

Answer (score 0):

You can't eager-fetch heterogeneous associations (i.e. `Any`) in a single roundtrip. Also, this won't help much if you have a recursive/hierarchical relationship.

There are two techniques to help you with performance that apply here: [batching](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch) and [caching](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-cache).

Comment: Is it possible to batch these? The crux of the issue seems to be not knowing what the next record is prior to grabbing the one before it. I guess I was hoping there was some magic bullet to grab a tree starting at X root with a filter to prevent recursion (I do note which records are potentially recursive in the database). Guess I'll have to investigate this after I put caching in place. Thanks!

Comment: There are no magic bullets. Recursive SQL is nonstandard, so there is no support for it in NH. But you can always write a recursive SqlQuery and grab the entities from there. Or maybe you could rethink the hierarchy: how about linking all the steps to the Wizard instead, as a simple collection?

Comment: It's much more than a simple wizard at this point; it's a fairly complex logical graph with links across any individual group boundary. Do you recommend attempting to load records into NH using a stored procedure or would you say it would be better to consume it directly into the view model objects I return? I don't need to do anything other than display them; very much a reporting thing.